# Is there a way to make a non deep copy of a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, copy, jpanel

Alright I have a JPanel (I'm using NetBeans and swing) that I would like to make a copy of and use it in another tab, meaning it uses the same layout as the other panel but I dont want to make a deep copy of it. Cause if I make a deep copy of it when I change one I change the other. Is there any way to just make a copy of what it looks like without it having the ties to the original

Answer (score 3):

Seems that you have misunderstood the word "deep copy" - a deep copy just has the effect of **not** being tied to the original, in contrast to a **shallow copy**, which leaves such ties.

Anyway, creating copies of whole Swing component trees is nothing which is really supported - it could be done by serialization, though.

But why can't you simply use the same code which created your original JPanel (with the components in it) and create a new one?

Comment: Sorry yeh got my words mixed up I meant one without ties. And I an using the desktop application function of net beans. So it is making the code for me. The thing I'm trying to have it do is I have a phone book with tabs for each of the people. I have a template tab that has how it is supposed to look so if they add a new contact it creates a new tab with that template.so I was looking for a way to just make a copy of that tablet so they could use the add feature multiple times

Comment: Netbeans generated some code for your template tab. Move this code in a separate method if it isn't already, and invoke it once for each tab you want to populate.

Answer (score 0):

Here is method for solving the following problem without coding just using design views of JPanels/JFrames.

You can go to Navigator in design view select all JPanel components and copy them by typing ctrl+a and ctrl+c. Then create another one JPanel and in design view, just paste them with ctrl+v.

Result: You get all components same size, dimensions and positions with same properties and values. After you do this, you can easily change whatever you want by using properties of GUI forms.

Answer (score -1):

You actually cannot make a copy of a Swing component that is tied to the original. Components can only share models.

You can make a clone of your panel which will be totally separate panel in no way tied to the original.

Answer (score -1):

You're using Matisse UI-designer in Netbeans IDE? Then you can just select your designed JPanel, copy it to the clipboard and paste into the other form.